# Model is null in mvc aspx view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

i am new to mvc. I am trying to use conditions like if else in my "view" but it throws a object reference error at "Model.sayHello".

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<myMVC.Models.myMVCMaster>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "myMaster", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SubmitForm" }))
       { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
    <% if(Model.sayHello) {
      <div>Hello world!</div>
    <% }
       } %>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
public class myMasterController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(myMVCMaster model)
    {            
        model.InitializePage();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(myMVCMaster model, string Command)
    {  
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class myMVCMaster
{
    private bool _sayHello = false;
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool sayHello{ get { return _sayHello; } set { _sayHello = value; } }

    public void InitializePage()
    {
    }
}
```

Why my model is returning as null?

Comment: Have you even configured the project to use Razor? The other code in the view (`<%... %>`) is using ASPX

Comment: you have combine two syntax over here

Comment: I think your view is not using razor view engine it is using old aspx view engine.. so try using <% %> instead of @.

Comment: No, i have never worked on mvc before..

Comment: `@` prefix only worked in CSHTML/VBHTML files, not ASPX files. To use Razor prefix you need to convert ASPX to CSHTML file and all master pages converted to layout pages.

Comment: is there any way to use if statement in aspx..

Comment: Just use ASPX code block `<% if (condition) { // statements } else { // statements } %>`. All server side scripts should be enclosed by `<% ... %>` to be worked.

Comment: i tried <% if (sayHello) { } %> and <% if (Model.sayHello) { } %>
but then it throws object refrence error. :(

Comment: For the [HttpGet] method you need to pass the model, or you should create class object inside method insted of passing as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because the model is not initialized in the controller method. For `HttpGet` controller actions, you model should be in initialize state before it is passed it to `view`.

Declare your controller method like this -

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{   
    myMVCMaster model = new myMVCMaster();
    model.InitializePage();
    return View(model);
}
```